# Por que está dando "Uncaught ReferenceError: getSetorObj is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Está dizendo que "getSetorObj" não está definido, mas o método existe e está na classe Mapa. O erro é na linha 38 do script.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var jogo = new Jogo();
 jogo.init();
});

function Setor(X, Y){     //Classe Setor: Cada setor do mapa
 var x = X, y = Y;     // Coordenadas xy do setor 
 var id = "x" + x + "y" + y;  // id do div do setor
 this.get = function(){   // retorna o objeto JQuery do setor
  return $("#" + id);
 }
 
 $("#mapa").append("<div class=\"setor\" id=\"" + id + "\" ></div>" ); // Adiciona div do setor ao mapa
}

function Mapa(TamX, TamY){
 var tamX = TamX, tamY = TamY;
 var setores = [];
 
 for(i = 1; i <= tamY; i++){
  for(j = 1; j <= tamX; j++){
   setores[tamX * (i - 1) + j] = new Setor(j, i);
  }
  $("#x" + 1 + "y" + i).css("clear", "left");
 }
 
 this.getSetorObj = function(x, y){
  return $("#x" + x + "y" + y);
 }
 
 
 var atualiza = function(){
  
 
 }
 
 this.selectSetor = function(X, Y){
  getSetorObj(X, Y).css("background-color", "red");
 }
 this.destSetor = function(X, Y){
  getSetorObj(X, Y).css("background-color", "lightblue");
 }
 this.getTamX = function(){
  return tamX;
 }
 this.getTamY = function(){
  return tamY;
 }
 this.getSetor = function(x, y){
  return setores[tamX * (y - 1) + x]
 }
}

function Jogo(){
 mapa = new Mapa(10, 10);
 var initX, initY;
 var setoresJogador = [];
 

 
 this.init = function(){
  initX = Math.floor((Math.random() * mapa.getTamX()) + 1);
  initY = Math.floor((Math.random() * mapa.getTamY()) + 1);
  
  setorInit = {x: initX, y: initY};
  setoresJogador.push(setorInit);
  mapa.selectSetor(initX, initY);
  atualiza();
 }
 
 var addSetorJog = function(novoSetor){
  setoresJogador.push(novoSetor);
  atualiza();
 }
 
 var getSetoresAdj = function(setores){
  var setoresAdjacentes = []; 
  for(i=0; i<setores.length; i++){
   var setor = setores[i];
   for(j= (-1); j<=1; j++){
    for(k= (-1); k<=1; k++){
     if(j!=0 || k!=0){
      var x = setor.x + j;
      var y = setor.y + k;
      if((x >= 1 && x <= mapa.getTamX()) && (y >=1 && y <= mapa.getTamY()))
       setoresAdjacentes.push({x: x, y: y});
                        }
    }
   }
  }
  return setoresAdjacentes;
 }
 var atualiza = function(){
  adjacentes = getSetoresAdj(setoresJogador);
  for(i=0; i<adjacentes.length; i++){
   var setor = adjacentes[i];
   mapa.destSetor(setor.x, setor.y);
   mapa.getSetorObj(setor.x, setor.y).click(function(){
    setoresJogador.push({x: setor.x, y: setor.y});
   });
  }
 }
}

function Jogador(){




}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
  .setor{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   float: left;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border: solid 1px lightblue;
   background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="mapa">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa especificar o `this.` para chamar a função `getSetorObj` naquela linha (e em outras também). Se você não usa esse prefixo, a função

```
this.selectSetor = function(X, Y){
    getSetorObj(X, Y).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

é equivalente a

```
this.selectSetor = function(X, Y){
    [[global]].getSetorObj(X, Y).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

E aquela função não está definida no escopo global. Usando o `this` você vai usar o escopo correto.

```
this.selectSetor = function(X, Y){
    this.getSetorObj(X, Y).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: Era isso, obrigado.